# Run API Gateway Tutorial locally

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I've successfully deployed the app from the tutorial here: [https://github.com/awslabs/aws-api-gateway-developer-portal](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-api-gateway-developer-portal%20to%20AWS.%20I%20can%20run%20it%20from%20the%20generated%20URL%20and%20make%20some%20minor%20modifications%20to%20UI.)

Now, how can I either heavily customize the client or write a new one? Can I somehow do development locally and point the app to AWS resources. Are there any tutorials to do smth like that - write client and then integrate it with AWS IAM, Lambda and API Gateway. Or I have to do that within AWS environment? In this case do I use something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to what I'm trying to accomplish in this great detailed tutorial: https://serverless-stack.com/. Probably the most eloquent tutorial I've ever come across. I'm surprised that such information is so hard to find. AWS docs and tutorials are very poorly maintained and other than general concepts are not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Serverless stack uses the serverless framework which has good documentation and examples. There is a plugin called serverless-offline which can host your API gateway endpoints locally, so you can test things out before you deploy.

http://serverless.com/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline